# Are the theorems g•f injective/surjective then f/g is injective/surjective invertible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, proof-writing, set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

i have questions.

I know that:

if $g \circ f$ is surjective than g is surjective;

If $g \circ f$ is injective than f is injective;

If g and f are both injective than $g \circ f$ is injective;

If g and f are both surjective than $g \circ f$ is surjective;

My questions are:

1. if g is surjective is $g \circ f$ surgective? I know it is not but i would like to see a proof and a counterexample
2. if f is injective is $g \circ f$ injective? Same as above
3. if g is surjective and f is injective is $g \circ f$ biijective?

Thanks

Comment: For 1., you know that if $f$ is sujrective it won't be a counter-example. So try to choose $f$ as far away from surjective as possible. What type of function is the complete opposite of surjective? Likewise for 2., you can try to choose $g$ as far away from injective as possible. What would that look like?

Comment: I thoutht: i took g: N -> {0,1}, if x=2n than g(x)=0, if x=2n+1 than g(x)=1, n belongs to N, g is surjective but not injective. f: N -> N and f(x)= 2x, f is injective but not sujective. g(f(x))=0 so g is neither injective or sujective. Thank.

Comment: If someone else has other examples or proofs i would like to see them

Comment: Have you thought about using constant functions? They are very simple examples of functions that are extremely not surjective and extremely not injective.

Comment: Yes, i took f: R->R with f(x)= k, where k is an arbitrary number chosen from R, no matter what g: R ->R is (injective/sujective), g(f(x)) is neither injective or sujective

Comment: So that seems to answer 1. Try the same with $g$ to answer 2.

Comment: If i take g: R ->R, g(x)=k for every x in R than it doesn t matter who f is (injective or not) g(f(x))= k for every x in R